# constexpr: Why my expression is not a constant expression?

Tags: c++, constexpr, static-assert

I want to define a buffer at compile-time and check its size with a `static_assert`:

```
struct Buffer{
    int* array;
    size_t size;
};

template<typename T, int size>
struct ConstArray{
  T arr[size];

  constexpr ConstArray(T t[size]):arr(){
    for(int e = 0; e < size; e++)
      arr[e] = t[e];
  }

  constexpr const T& operator[](size_t e)const{
    return &arr[e];
  }
};

struct A {
    Buffer* b;
};

constexpr ConstArray<A, 1> a_maps(    
    (A[]){(Buffer[]){(int[]){0,1,2}, 3}} // error: constexpr variable 'a_maps' must be initialized by a constant expression 
);

int main()
{
    static_assert(a_maps[0].b->size == 3, "NOP"); // error: static assertion expression is not an integral constant expression
    return 0;
}
```

Any advice to make this approach viable?

https://godbolt.org/z/W1xGd4n5b

Comment: Why is you `operator[]` returning a pointer instead of a reference? Also, its argument should really have the type `size_t`.

Comment: And `(int[]){0,1,2}` is a compound literal which doesn't exist in C++, only in C.

Comment: is my expression not considered constant because it is a compound literal ?

Comment: It's a non-standard and non-portable extension of the C++ language, so I don't know. You have to read the manual for whatever compiler you use.

Comment: `(A[])` isn't valid either.

Comment: I don't have time for a proper answer. A viable approach would be to use more `const`: https://godbolt.org/z/Ydrzovv7a

Comment: @AndyG Thanks for this approach. compound literal was to prevent me from using more const

Comment: @Xemuth constexpr data is... well, `const` . You cannot assign a non-const type to a const type. (Well, you could cast away the `const`, which is actually fine so long as you never ever attempt to mutate it: https://godbolt.org/z/769Y5Ej19)

Comment: @Xemuth Why do you need to avoid that?

Comment: @user17732522 feel like it is more clear to have every value declared in my initializer list instead of having to declare all my constant and then reference them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(A[]){/*...*/}` and `(int[]){0,1,2}` are not valid standard-C++ syntax. Your compiler is only supporting them as an extension called *compound literals*, which comes from C.

Because the standard doesn't know anything about this syntax, it is mostly pointless to argue whether or not your code should be a constant expression. It will be completely up to the compiler.

It is not a good idea to use them in C++ code because compound literals *look* like they are similar to `T{...}` syntax in C++, but in C they actually behave very differently. They have a different storage duration, lifetime, and value category. So immediately, it isn't even obvious whether the C++ extension will behave like the C syntax in C, or more similar to the C++ constructs. It is necessary to verify in the compiler documentation to not accidentally cause Undefined Behavior.

Compile with `-pedantic-errors` to get GCC and Clang to complain about this extension in C++ mode (or `-pedantic` if you only want warnings).

---

If you replace the compound literals with `constexpr`-qualified array variables, then it should pass the assertion.

Comment: Thanks it's very clear. Compound literals in my C++ code with my compiler had the advantage of producting static value without needing me to declare each member of StaticBuffer

Comment: @Xemuth That's already potentially a mistaken assumption about the syntax. As far as I know GCC, and therefore probably also Clang, use the C++ temporary object behavior of compound literals in C++ mode. In that case the arrays won't have static storage duration because they are temporary objects that are never bound to a reference and therefore don't have their lifetime extended. Consequently you will have dangling pointers in the variable, which already disqualifies it from being declared `constexpr` under C++ rules (and will cause UB if you try to use the pointers).